# RowFilter expression of DataTable for subtracting two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, rowfilter

Can anyone correct my RowFilter expression to subtract two dates where one date is database table column and other date is current date. Below is my code snippet where i am checking whether difference between the dates is less than or equal to 10."CreationDateTime" is database table column.With this code i am getting missing operand error.

```
dataQuery = string.Format("(CreationDateTime - (" + DateTime.Now + "))<={0}",10);
myDataView.RowFilter = dataQuery;
```

Comment: Have you tried to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be create another column (creating another column in your query) for the difference hours between them and creating a filter after that.

You can use [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to get's difference current date and return `int` as an hour like;

```
DATEDIFF(hh, CreationDateTime, GETDATE()) as HourDiff
```

and you can filter that in your `DataTable` like;

```
myDataView.RowFilter = "HourDiff <= 10";
```